# Rename-Computer works fine unless I try to use $credentials

Tags: powershell

If I try to run the script below, I get a WMI access denied error.  Yet if I run the command at the command line using the same credentials, it goes through without error.  Please explain what is wrong with the script.

This works fine at the command prompt:

> Rename-Computer -ComputerName U1004062-TLL-A -NewName U1004062-TLL-B -LocalCredential ten\LocalAdmin -DomainCredential ten\DomainAdmin -force -passthru -restart

This does not work using the same credentials.

```
Import-Module activedirectory
$list = Import-csv C:\temp\machine.csv -Header oldcomputer, newcomputer

$local = "domain"
$userlocal = "LocalAdmin"

#Don't edit below this point
$passwordlocal = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password for $userlocal" -AsSecureString
$usernamelocal = "$local\$userlocal"
$credentiallocal = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($usernamelocal, $passwordlocal)

$domain = "ten"
$user = "domainadmin"

#Don't edit below this point
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password for $user" -AsSecureString
$username = "$domain\$user"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)


foreach ($machine in $list) 
{Rename-Computer -ComputerName $machine.oldcomputer -NewName $machine.newcomputer -LocalCredential $credentiallocal -DomainCredential $credential -Force -passthru -Restart}
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why are you getting WMI errors when you are not using WMI? On another note.. try getting your credentials with `$credentialLocal = Get-Credential` and `$credential = Get-Credential`. Saves you some lines of code :) Alternatively, if you want the username filled out, use `$credentialLocal = Get-Credential -Message 'Please enter local credentials' -Username $username`

Comment: Thanks for the Tidbits of info OJK!  Apparently the Rename-Computer cmndlet uses WMI to make the change on the local machine.  I did figure out the problem though.  The company uses ARS and you must run everything through a proxy service to  do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure out the problem though. The company uses ARS and you must run everything through the ARS console and proxy service to do anything within AD.